# Making a set of images move cross the screen then when leaving the window, it comes up from the other side

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, animation, jquery-animate

I'm trying to implement the `marquee tag` in jQuery by animation a set of images using `animate()` function, making them move to the right or left direction.
But, I couldn't figure out when a single image goes to the end of the screen returns **individually**  to the other side.
Because I heard that the window size is not constant for every browser, So is there anyway to implement that?
this is what I came up so far(it's simple and basic):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    moveThumbs(500);
    function moveThumbs(speed){
        $('.thumbnails').animate({
            right:"+=150"
        }, speed);
        setTimeout(moveThumbs, speed);
    }

});
```

**note**: I searched in SO for related questions, but had no luck to find exact information for my specific issue.

Comment: You can use jQuery to obtain the current window width and decide how far to make the animation run before resetting it to the other side.  Then, no matter what the width, your animation will go just off the edge.

Comment: @jfriend00 What about resetting each image to the other side? for example if a singe image hit the right side it will be returned to the left side

Comment: If you want both sides animating at the same time (as if it was wrapping around), then you will need two images as you can't have one image in the two places at the same time.  If you just want it to finish on one edge and then appear on the other edge, you just have to calculate how far you want it to animate based on the window  width and then when that animation completes (using the completion function), you move the image to the other side and start animating it again.

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't want the image to be in 2 places at the same time.to make it clear,let's say I have 20 images all of them moving to the edge, when the image(no.20) hits the edge it will go back to the other side, while image(19)is moving till it hits the edge and then go back,etc.

Comment: I added an answer that shows one way to do it with jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a basic script that moves an image across the screen and then resumes on the other side and adapts to the window width.

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/rnWa2/

```
function startMoving(img) {
    var img$ = $(img);
    var imgWidth = img$.width();
    var screenWidth = $(window).width();
    var amount = screenWidth - (parseInt(img$.css("left"), 10) || 0);
    // if already past right edge, reset to 
    // just left of left edge
    if (amount <=0 ) {
        img$.css("left", -imgWidth);
        amount = screenWidth + imgWidth;
    }
    var moveRate = 300;   // pixels per second to move
    var time = amount * 1000 / moveRate;
    img$.stop(true)
        .animate({left: "+=" + amount}, time, "linear", function() {
            // when animation finishes, start over
            startMoving(this);
        })
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    // readjust if window changes size
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $(".mover").each(function() {
            startMoving(this);
        });
    });
});
```

​    ​

Comment: The code didn't work for me,I'm not sure way. maybe because it is wrapped in a div.

Comment: @AzizAG - You had a bunch of problems with your jsFiddle - most to do with the settings on the left panel (not the code).  I cleaned it up for you: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/PbgqP/

Comment: One more thing, when setting the position of `.mover` to `absolute` all of the images are stacked on top of each other(i have like 20), and cant separate them, what's the solution?

Comment: @AzizAG - Set a different `top` CSS value for each image to separate them vertically.  See how I did it for two images in my jsFiddle.

Comment: I was thinking of a dynamic solution. guess this is the only solution.

Comment: @AzizAG - the `top` value can be set with code too, but you'd have to write code to set each one to whatever you want.  Since you have never shown your whole page to show what you're really trying to do overall, I have no idea what you want.  You will have to position the images vertically one way or the other.

Comment: i noticed something, when I leave the window, the images are stacked. like this: http://jsfiddle.net/uVsQ5/2/ , just open it then change the window. few seconds and it will be stacked on each other!

Comment: @AzizAG - Your code is responsible for making sure the images don't overlap if that's what you want.  Timers for animation will change/stop in some browsers when a tabbed window is not visible and this may affect the animation and relative position of different images.

Comment: @jfriend00: how would you give the ability for the image to explode on click. I have decreased the speed of the image and added an explode function: $(this).hide('explode', {pieces: 98 }, 2000), on an onclick event.(Using JqueryUI) but cause both images are class mover it does not work. Do they need to be named differently?